# Can someone make the world larger in Console Edition

Tags: xbox-360, minecraft-legacy-console

Accoding to the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Console_Edition), the worlds are very small (limited to 864x864 blocks). They are like this because consoles have low storing spaces. But, if one would acquire a larger disk space for the console, can worlds be made bigger? For Xbox 360, please.

Answer (score 1):

Not unless they update the game to have that feature (unlikely that they'll do that specifically since it only applies to the previous-gen consoles).

From your link:

> Since not all Xbox 360s and PS3s ship with hard drives, these two consoles support limited worlds only.

The big advantage with programming for consoles is that you can assume every console is the same. Allowing for completely different game systems (not just actual size, but the sort of *virtual memory* used on the PC) depending on console configuration would be a real inconvenience for development.

Maybe if they expected Xbox 360 to provide a lot of sales going forward, they would consider it.

But your question was as to if you could do it yourself, to which I'll just straight up say:

Probably never.

Comment: As SvJ0hn says, it adds a great deal of convenience being able to assume what hardware the user is running the game on. Just because you have a bigger hard drive, doesn't mean the guy trying to join your game does. And then you would have all sorts of issues.